# Can't install webrtcvad

Tags: python, windows, command-line, pip, webrtc

I can't install webrtcvad. I try pip install webrtcvad and it gives this.

> Collecting webrtcvad
> Using cached webrtcvad-2.0.10.tar.gz (66 kB)
> Using legacy 'setup.py install' for webrtcvad, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
> Installing collected packages: webrtcvad
> Running setup.py install for webrtcvad ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'c:\users\horus50\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Horus50\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ebpov27w\webrtcvad\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Horus50\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ebpov27w\webrtcvad\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Horus50\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-udzesqbs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\horus50\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\webrtcvad'
> cwd: C:\Users\Horus50\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ebpov27w\webrtcvad
> Complete output (19 lines):
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
> copying webrtcvad.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
> running build_ext
> building '_webrtcvad' extension
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits\webrtc
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits\webrtc\common_audio
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits\webrtc\common_audio\signal_processing
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits\webrtc\common_audio\vad
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_WIN32 -Icbits -Ic:\users\horus50\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\horus50\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include" /Tccbits\pywebrtcvad.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\cbits\pywebrtcvad.obj
> pywebrtcvad.c
> c:\users\horus50\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
> ----------------------------------------
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\horus50\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Horus50\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ebpov27w\webrtcvad\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Horus50\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ebpov27w\webrtcvad\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Horus50\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-udzesqbs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\horus50\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\webrtcvad' Check the logs for full command output.
> WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.1; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\horus50\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I am on windows 10 how do I fix this?

Comment: using Visual Studio??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+webrtcvad and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error+C1083%3A+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+%27io.h%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory